# i am trying to transfer my data from csv file to postgres table, during insert i don"t want to mention how many columns i have?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

i dont want to use multiple %s, is there a simple way to just count the columns instead of writing %s and applying it in insert area
such as multiplying the %s with no. of columns

```
    with open('Book1.csv', 'r') as file:
       reader = csv.reader(file)
       next(reader)
       for row in reader:
           cur.execute(" insert into student values (%s, %s, %s)", row)
```

Comment: Why not use [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from)?

Comment: Why not use pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html ?